# In what case does the parameter of surface tension vary?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics, surface-tension

[image: A question]

I was trying to solve a question regarding force of surface tension,it happens that I was unable to solve it using F = T*l,But it happens that the intended solution was to be done such that F =T*2l,but I'm not sure if it should be this was this,there are no two surfaces to the needle or to the water.

How is it that the force varies without change number of surfaces? How is that the shape of the object can make the number of surfaces vary with ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surface tension acts tangentially to the surface of water, So when you immerse a nail in the water, water from both sides are being in effect [image]

Hence 2*L is used in the formula